# Tkinter: width of grid got changed while packing second label on

Tags: python, tkinter

the problem that i met is when the second tk.Label through 'grid' got packed into GUI (which is triggere by function 'click_questionmark' mimicing pop-up like suggestion), the tk.Entry items lies just over it will be expanded.

see screenshots below:

[image: before click on questionmark]
[image: after]

as seen the space between 'Filepath' and Entry was shrinked.

appreciate any help.

code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class KWS_GUI:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.title('Workflow')
    self.root.geometry("800x300")
    self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.root.config(background="white")
    #self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=15)
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    
    self.questionmark = Image.open('fragezeichen.png')
    self.questionmark = self.questionmark.resize((15,15))
    self.questionmark = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.questionmark)

    self.filename = ""
    self.filename = tk.StringVar(self.root, self.filename)
    #Alle Knöpfe
    self.selectbutton = tk.Button(master=self.root, 
                                  text='Select', 
                                  command=self.select_function)
    self.selectbutton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='EW')
    #self.selectbutton.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT)

    self.question1 = tk.Button(master=self.root, 
                               background="white", 
                               foreground="white", 
                               image=self.questionmark,
                               relief=tk.FLAT,
                               command=self.click_questionmark)
    self.question1.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='W')
    #self.question1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT)

    #Alle Textfelder
    self.filefeld = tk.Entry(master=self.root, 
                             textvariable=self.filename, 
                             relief=tk.SOLID)
    self.filefeld.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='EW')
    self.filetitle = tk.Label(master=self.root, 
                              text="Filepath:", 
                              background="white", 
                              relief=tk.FLAT)
    self.filetitle.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')




    self.root.mainloop()

def click_questionmark(self):
    self.suggestion1 = tk.Label(master=self.root,
                                text="Wähle bitte den entsprechenden Probenbegleitzettel aus!",
                                foreground="red",
                                background="white")
    self.suggestion1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='EW')

KWS_GUI()
```

it turns out that the length of text too long...which requires more space than the entry as i have tried with only 'a' in label and before/after packing remains the entry same length

Comment: The indentation isn't correct probably.

Comment: Where is  `select_function` function?

Comment: Your code is okay.

Comment: @toyota Supra because that function is not related to this issue so i just left it out

Comment: Since the default width of an `Entry` widget is 20 characters, so the space allocated for it will be smaller than the later label which is 55 characters long. If you set `width=10` when creating the label, it won't produce the issue.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the text is too long to fit? Do you want the text to be truncated? Wrapped to the next line? Something else?